# chrome webdriverを使用して画像を取得したい

Tags: python, web-scraping, chromedriver

特定の自動車モデルの画像をGoogleイメージ検索を使って自動的にダウンロードするためのPythonスクリプトを作成しています.
しかし, webdriverが起動して検索を行うことは可能ですが, 画像の取得に失敗しそのままプログラムが終了してしまいます.
Selenium4を使用しています.

以下, ソースコードです.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse

# Google ImagesのURL
url = "https://www.google.com/imghp"

# 検索クエリのリスト（自動車モデル名）
queries = [
    "2007 Honda Element",
    "2003 Honda Element",
    "2009 Honda Element",
    # 他のモデルも同様に追加
]

# 保存先ディレクトリ
save_dir = "car_images"

# 保存先ディレクトリが存在しない場合は作成
if not os.path.exists(save_dir):
    os.makedirs(save_dir)

# Chrome WebDriverを起動
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # chromedriverのパスを指定

# 明示的な待機の設定
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for query in queries:
    driver.get(url)
    search_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "q")))
    search_box.clear()
    search_box.send_keys(query)
    search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    # 「画像」リンクが表示されるまで待機
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "画像"))).click()

    # スクロールして画像を読み込む
    for _ in range(5):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,1000)")
        time.sleep(1)  # スクロールごとに短い待機

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    img_tags = soup.find_all("img")

    # 画像をダウンロード（ファイル名にインデックスを追加）
    for index, img in enumerate(img_tags):
        img_url = img.get("src")
        if img_url and img_url.startswith("http"):
            img_response = requests.get(img_url)
            if img_response.status_code == 200:
                img_data = img_response.content
                img_name = os.path.join(save_dir, f"{query.replace(' ', '_')}_{index}.jpg")
                with open(img_name, "wb") as img_file:
                    img_file.write(img_data)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: 技術的な話とは別に、Google の検索結果をスクレイピングすることは規約で禁止されていた気がします。

Comment: `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "画像"))).click()` リンクテキストが「画像」であるHTML要素がありませんので、ここでエラーになります。(`TimeoutException`)